# iOS: isMovingToParentViewController is not working as expected

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

My setup is simple, and my issue is not very different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777796/ismovingtoparentviewcontroller-always-returning-false-for-root-view-controller-o). However to better explain it I have posted it here:

```
NavController -> VC1 -> VC2
```

VC1 is root view controller of NavController.
VC2 is accessible via Push segue from VC1.

I want to detect, within VC1, whether:

It appeared directly as root view controller (via Push)
It appeared as a result of VC2 being popped

I read the docs which says following should tell me if later is true.

```
isMovingToParentViewController == NO
```

However that is not the case, and above condition ALWAYS turns out to be TRUE.
Which means that, (self.isMovingToParentViewController == NO) is always happening.

Here is my code:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    //pushed to stack
    if (self.isMovingToParentViewController == YES)
    {
        //First time
      }
    else
    //popped off
    {
        //via Pop from VC2
    }    
}
```

Same is the case for viewDidAppear, too.

For a matter of fact check, I put breakpoint at the start, and checked that all of the following are FALSE, in both cases:

```
([self isMovingFromParentViewController])
([self isMovingToParentViewController])
([self isBeingPresented])
([self isBeingDismissed])
```

What is happening?
Is there anything I goofed up in my storyboard?
Please help...

Comment: Does it help if you add the expected call to `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` to the start of your `viewWillAppear:` method?

Comment: I did include that line at the very beginning of `viewWillAppear`, but to no result.

Comment: All four of those methods should return `NO` in `VC1` when `VC2` is popped. But I would expect `isMovingToParentViewController` to return `YES` the very 1st time that `VC1` is displayed.

Comment: What I've always used to do this in viewWillAppear is to use `[self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:self]`  It will be false if self is being pushed, true if we're popping back to self.

Comment: Some experimentation shows that isMovingToParentViewController is only true when a viewController is being pushed to a navigation stack.  It's not set for the rootViewController.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, isMovingToParentViewController isn't true for the root view controller, so I usually handle this situation with a BOOL,

```
@implementation ViewController {
    BOOL isFirstAppearance;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    isFirstAppearance = YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (isFirstAppearance) {
        NSLog(@"root view controller is moving to parent");
        isFirstAppearance = NO;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"root view controller, not moving to parent");
    }
}
```

Comment: This fails with state restoration when a hierarchy is restored because the first time the root VCs view is loaded is when going back.

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution is by adding a flag on `viewWillDisappear` setting it to YES if the VC1 has been disappeared. Else the view has never been disappeared so it is the first push (`RootViewController` of `Navigation Controller`).

***Example Code***

```
BOOL hasDisappeared;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (hasDisappeared==YES) {
        //VC2 has been popped
    }
    else
    {
        //VC1 is the rootViewController
    }
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //Pushing to VC2
    hasDisappeared=YES;
}
```

Comment: I was just typing a very similar answer. I've been doing this since long before the `isMovingToParentViewController` method was added.

Comment: This is the simplest way, another method I was going to write was @rdelmar for viewDidLoad, but I just came up with this idea.

Comment: Can `UINavigationControllerDelegate` help? This approach is quite simple but doesn't necessarily address Push Pop thing. Surprising we have so many methods and none of them useful!

Comment: I quite don't get you @NiravBhatt, the idea here is that when the VC1 is disappeared, it has been pushed to VC2. in viewWillAppear when the hasDisappeared=YES, VC2 has been popped.

Comment: What I meant is that this solution doesn't exactly address Push/Pop event in case of root view controller. In any case, this is inevitable and considering the timestamp I have marked @rdelmar's answer. +1 for your help.

Comment: I have updated the question, tell me where is the part that you don't understand? Is the same logic as @rdelmar, and considering timestamp, I am first but that doesn't matter, hope that you have fixed your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since it appears that `isMovingToParentViewController` is only set when a viewController is being pushed to the navigation stack, and not set for the initial rootViewController, I'd suggest using the following:

```
 if([self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:self])
 {
     // being popped to self here
 }
 else
 {
     // being pushed here
 }
```

Comment: But wouldn't the `if` be true when `self` is the root controller and it is being shown for the 1st time?

Comment: Looks like you're correct @rmaddy.  Guess I've never used it for the rootViewController before...

Comment: @rmaddy is right. `if([self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:self])` always turns out to be TRUE.

Comment: Looked back and I was actually using it to trigger completion blocks in `viewWillDisappear:` not `viewWillAppear:`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check isMovingFromParentViewController in VC2’s viewWillDissapear and call a delegate method implemented in VC1. I.e. VC2 is being removed from its parent nav controller because of being popped.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative flag way ,

if your viewController doesn't support gesture popping,

```
     var onceDo = true

     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if onceDo{
            // ...
            //  VC1 is the rootViewController
            onceDo = false
        }
        else{
            //VC2 has been popped
        }
    }
```